# Is the phrase "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" too open-ended?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, site-faq

On more than one occasion, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892846/code-snippet-when-applying-for-an-android-job#comment12621504_9892846) happen.  A user posts an off-topic question, and then tries to justify it by quoting this phrase from the FAQ.  How many new users are confused by this phrase, but never say so?

Is it time to either replace this phrase with something else, or eliminate it from that portion of the FAQ?

I think seasoned community members read this phrase as a mandate: *"You should only ask questions that are unique to the programming profession."*  But I think new people see it as a permission: *"I can ask my question as long as it relates to the programming profession."*

Given that the FAQ is supposed to be the gold standard for what the site is about, and a reference guide that we constantly point new users to for guidance, wouldn't it make sense to eliminate this ambiguity?

**NOTE:** My suggestion would be just to remove the phrase from the FAQ.  "Practical, answerable problems" is [already adequately covered](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) in the FAQ, and the remaining three bullet points in the introduction very clearly state what is on-topic.

Comment: I guess so? I am not sure how this is **not** a yes or no question.

Comment: I retagged the question to make my intention clearer.

Comment: maybe add the `faq-proposed` tag?

Comment: That tag is for [these faqs.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931)

Comment: I guess there is a difference between *programmers* and *people who program because they were hired to do so*. Programmers wouldn't need any clarification in the FAQ.

Comment: @six: If your question involves code or programming tools, you don't need the "programmer" title after your name for your question to be on-topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I missed your note. I'm merely commenting that the site is usually intuitive to programmers (regardless of actual profession).

Comment: Yes, we really need to change the wording on this. The discussion around [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5119424/19679) is an example of how this is leading to problems. [This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22unique+to+the+programming+profession%22+-site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com) shows many other examples of people trying to defend clearly off-topic questions using this clause.

Comment: How about something like `"subject to the above, practical ..."`? Or slight rephrasing and move it after `"... ask your question!"`?

Comment: @Dukeling: This question is more than a year old now... See my new take on this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175175/please-change-the-way-practical-answerable-problems-that-are-unique-to-the-pro

Answer (score 7):

In other SE FAQs, the opening bullet point list is for allowable topics. For example, [on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), the bullet point list is:

> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - design patterns
> - developer testing
> - development methodologies
> - freelancing and business concerns
> - quality assurance
> - software architecture
> - software engineering
> - software licensing

And [on Super User](https://superuser.com/faq), it's:

> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking

With the understanding that those are allowable topics as long as they are scoped to the site's topical focus. If, for example, your question on Programmers is about freelancing and business concerns *and* it uniquely applies to "professional programmers interested in software development", then it's on-topic.

While most Stack Overflow users aren't likely to have been SE 2.0/SU/SF members first, the reason many of the SE 2.0 sites use that format is because it seems to effectively communicate what topics are covered by the site.

Now, take [Stack Overflow's FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), which is:

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

If one applies the same principles as the other FAQs, this would suggest that *all* "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" are on topic as long as they (uniquely?) apply to "professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it".

At best, that's a tautology; at worst, it's exactly what you describe: a license to ask any question as long as it's unique to the programming profession, which covers far more than the type of questions that are actually on-topic on Stack Overflow (covered by the first three bullet points).

So yeah, purge it with the fire of a thousand suns.